# How to get the selected value of a drop down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to show the selected value of a drop down, but its not selected the dropdown value, but adding another value to the dropdown list.

here is the code I am using:

**jquery**

```
var companyId = $(this).closest('tr').find('#headquarterIdForSearch').text();
                var companyName = $(this).closest('tr').find('#companyNameId').text();
                $(this).parents().find('.hqSelect option:selected').val(companyId).text(companyName);
```

The above code is not selecting the value that I am assigning to the **Text** and **val** property. However, it is adding a new property. Lets say, I have fetched value for **companyName** as "FIS" and companyId as 123.

The value is present under the dropdown however, it is adding a new value to the dropdown.

How can I show the selected value? I have also used the below code:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

Thanks,

Comment: add your html dropdown list code

Answer (score 2):

```js
alert($('#id').val());

function demo()
{
  alert($('#id').val());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='id' onchange="demo()">
  <option value="1">Vijay  </option>
  <option value="2">Raj  </option>
  <option value="3">Ganesh  </option>
  <option value="4">Ram  </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<option value="one">One</option>

$('#dropDownId').val();
```

It will give the selected option value ie. value="one" from above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.val()` function to get the value, you don't need to pass any argument.

```
$(this).parents().find('.hqSelect').val()
```